# writing a program for Transferring ownership owner to owner for all objects

Tags: apex, schema, dynamic-apex, for

I'm writing a program for transferring ownership dynamically. But It has to work for all objects.

```
Public Class TransferOwnership{
@AuraEnabled
public static string tranferRecordOwnership(String obj,string fromowneremail,string toowneremail){
    list<sobject> objupdate=new list<sobject>();
    list<user> olduser=[select id from user where email=:fromowneremail];
    list<user> newuser=[select id from user where email=:toowneremail];
    list<Employee__c> newemp=[SELECT Id FROM Employee__c WHERE User__c =:newuser[0].id];
    string query = 'select Employee__c,Id,OwnerId';
    query=query + ' from ' + obj ;
    query=query + ' WHERE OwnerId =\''+olduser[0].id+'\'';
    system.debug('query===='+query);
    list<sobject> result=database.query(query);
    for(sobject re:result){
        re.ownerId=newuser[0].id;//***********It throwing an Error. dot function is not working 
        re.Employee__c=newemp[0].id;//***********It throwing an Error. dot function is not working 
        objupdate.add(re);
    }
    update objupdate;
    system.debug('query===='+result);
    string reccount=string.valueOf(result.size());
    return reccount;
}
}
```

I'm passing variables from lightning component.
But everything is working fine but I'm facing problems Sobject for loop. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

When working with a general `SObject` (as opposed to more concrete instances of the type like `Account`), we need to use the `get()` and `put()` methods that the SObject class provides to us ([Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)). This is just the price we have to pay for making things dynamic/abstract.

Applying that to your code would look like this:

```
re.put('ownerId', newuser[0].id);
re.put('Employee__c',newemp[0].id);
```

If I recall, both `get()` and `put()` are polymorphic. You can pass in strings that represent the field, or an `SObjectField` (field token).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this solution it's not working, If try to pass like this then it's throwing an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void set(String, Id) from the type SObject" . If I convert Id as string and then If I try to pass, again it's throwing an error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void set(String, String) from the type SObject"

Comment: @Gangadhar My mistake, the method name is "put", not "set". Answer updated.